# Convert to XTS by date AND time

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to convert a DF to xts
The following will actually convert my dataframe to xts but wipe out the H:M:S off the date column :

`EUR <- xts(EURUSD_5mins[,-1], order.by=as.Date(EURUSD_5mins$Date, format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))`

My date column in my DF looks like this : `2017-07-02 23:05:00`

Anyway I can keep the H M and S in my XTS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R's `Date` functions specifically work with Date data, which only go down to the day. If you want to preserve the time of day, you should use `as.POSIXct`.

```
# as.Date strips out the timestamp
as.Date(Sys.time(), format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
[1] "2018-01-13"

# as.POSIXct preserves it
as.POSIXct(Sys.time(), format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
[1] "2018-01-13 11:16:55 EST"
```

Comment: it's just what I found out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have used this : 
`intra <-as.POSIXct(EURUSD_5mins$Date, format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
EUR <-xts(EURUSD_5mins[,-1], order.by=intra)`
It works.